# Why does my Thread block in D when the parent process's window loses focus?

Tags: multithreading, d

I have a fairly simple D application, which uses a tkd (tcl) interface to parameterize and then launch a worker thread. The worker thread communicates its progress back to the UI periodically so that one can see what's going on. The worker thread is just an extension of the core.thread.Thread class.

Occasionally, but unreproducably, I observe that if I switch focus from the shell that launched the application to something else, the worker thread appears to block. It remains blocked until I return focus to the shell (not the GUI window). In fact, it appears to remain blocked indefinitely (i.e. I can go home, come back in the morning, and it's still blocked, and will still resume upon restoration of focus to the shell).

I'm curious about whether this could be attributable to something in D's threading implementation, or whether it might be something I've misunderstood about POSIX threading more generally. It's quite a persistent issue.

Comment: are you using any stdout text writing? it might be waiting for a chance to write...though it should be able to write in the background too.

Comment: Is your thread calling anything on the GUI that might block?

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe there are copious messages written to stdout, and I think this started shortly after I began mirroring the log there to debug some other issues. I also expect that stdout should be able to write in the background, but that might be the source of the issue.

Comment: @weltensturm no, once spun off, the child thread interacts with the GUI thread only via a very simple semaphored mailbox system for passing messages. i.e. child thread writes status information into a buffer, GUI reads that buffer periodically.

Comment: Have you tried running in a debugger and pausing when this happens? With this you should be able to see the blocking call.